# jQuery .animate() error I can't fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning jQuery and I am playing around with what it can do. I have the following code:

```
for(var i=0; i<501; i++) {
  document.write('<div style="width:40px; height:40px; background-color: red; margin: 2px; display: inline-block; float: left;"></div>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: '216px',
      width: '216px'
    }, 'slow');
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: '40px',
      width: '40px'
    }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

And I am having this issue that I can't understand. Whenever I click on the a box, I get an empty space in the left side of it. And I'd like that big box to be surrounded by the small boxes.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v85wrb6s/

Is there any way I can fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to re-position smaller boxes once one of them is clicked. You may find this useful http://gridster.net/